# Windows Fonts: Changing lfQuality in UIDLGLOGFONT within wxWidgets does not work well

Tags: windows, fonts, wxwidgets, font-family, cleartype

i'm trying to change the Font quality of a wxFont object. I use:

```
SetNativeFontInfo("0; -16; 0; 0; 0; 700; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 3; 48; Consolas");
```

to set the Font quality. Internally wxWdigets changes a UIDLGLOGFONT struct. The "3" represents the field lfQuality

```
#define NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY  3
```

That works fine. However the font family is changed somehow with only the quality token changed. The font is changed from a sans serif fixed font to a fixed font with serifs. Thats a big problem for me.

I looked further and found this when i looked up the internal values for font family:

[msdn UIDLGLOGFONT.lfPitchAndFamily Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.uidlglogfont.lfpitchandfamily.aspx)

in my case wxWidgets set UIDLGLOGFONT.lfPitchAndFamily to 48 which translates to FF_MODERN:

> Fonts with constant stroke width (monospace), with or without serifs. Monospace fonts are usually modern. Pica, Elite, and Courier New are examples.

Why does it state "with or without serifs"? How do you change the quality under wxWidgets without adding serifs?

Comment: wxWidgets has nothing to do with the Visual Studio Shell.  Your machine simply has very few fixed-pitch fonts installed.  When you say you want Consolas, a font that uses ClearType for anti-aliasing, but then say you don't want anti-aliasing then the font mapper is forced to find something else.  Probably picking Courier New, a font with serifs.  Change the face name to avoid surprises.

Comment: What would be a fixed font that doesn't use anti-aliasing?